# Different interpretation of system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

Given the variables

```
q1 = Root[(48 a^2 + 16 b) #^4 - (40 a^3 + 168 a b)#^3 + (-45 a^4 + 225 a^2 b + 72 b^2) #^2 + (27a^3 b - 162 a b^2) #+ 27 b^3 &,1]
q2 = Root[(48 a^2 + 16 b) #^4 - (40 a^3 + 168 a b)#^3 + (-45 a^4 + 225 a^2 b + 72 b^2) #^2 + (27a^3 b - 162 a b^2) #+ 27 b^3 &,2]
r1 = Root[375 a^8 - 3600 a^6 # + 8088 a^4 #^2 - 6912 a^2 #^3 + 2048 #^4 &,1]
r2 = Root[375 a^8 - 3600 a^6 # + 8088 a^4 #^2 - 6912 a^2 #^3 + 2048 #^4 &,2]
```

My intention is to solve the inequality $q_2 < c$ for a real number $c<0$ under the conditions $0<b<a^2$ and $a<0$. I first tried

```
Reduce[q2 < c && b > 0 && b < a^2 && a <0 && c <0,b,Reals]
```

which gives me a fairly nice solution to work with. However, if I split the domain of $b$ in two parts, namely $0<b<r_1$ and $r_1<b<a^2$

```
Reduce[q2 < c && b > 0 && b < r1 && c <0 && a <0,b,Reals]
```

and

```
Reduce[q2 < c && b > r1 && b < a^2 && c <0 && a <0,b,Reals]
```

then the outcomes are more complex involving an annoying root expression that bounds $a$. Where doest this come from? I assume it has something to do with the nature of the roots of the polynomial occurring in $q_2$? When I split the domain it looks like it threats $q_2$ differently then when I don't split the domain.

Comment: is it guaranteed  `0<r1<a^2` ?  Even if so `Reduce` might not recognise that from the root expression.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed guaranteed. This is due the fact that $r_1 \approx 0.14 a^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I'm unsure why you would expect adding a root expression as an additional constraint would not increase the complexity of the result.  Heres how I'd look at it:

For simplicity define some root expressions that end up in the `Reduce` results:

```
root1 = Root[-45 a^4 c^2 - 40 a^3 c^3 + 
     48 a^2 c^4 + (27 a^3 c + 225 a^2 c^2 - 168 a c^3 + 16 c^4) #1 +
     (-162 a c + 72 c^2) #1^2 + 27 #1^3 &, 1];
root2 = Root[
   544210944 c^8 - 3439853568 c^7 #1 + 9279799296 c^6 #1^2 - 
     13912793088 c^5 #1^3 +
     12599076608 c^4 #1^4 - 6972768000 c^3 #1^5 + 
     2248633440 c^2 #1^6 - 365310000 c #1^7 + 18984375 #1^8 &, 1];
```

your original result is this:

```
Reduce[q2 < c < 0 && 0 < b < a^2 && a < 0, b, Reals] /. 
 root1 -> HoldForm[root1]
```

> c < 0 && a < (4 c)/3 && root1<  b < a^2

now adding the additional constraint we get:

```
Reduce[q2 < c < 0 && 0 < b < r1 < a^2 && a < 0, b,  Reals] /. 
  {root1 -> HoldForm[root1], root2 -> HoldForm[root2], 
     r1 -> HoldForm[r1]}
```

> c < 0 && a < root2 && root1 <  b < r1

note indeed `Reduce` recognized that `r1<a^2`.  Now it turns out that `root2` is linear in c:

```
Plot[ {(4 c)/3, root2 }, {c, -10, 0}]
```

[image]

so your condition is :

> c < 0 && a < 11.1282 c && root1 <  b < r1

where that approximate number comes from: `root2/c /. c -> -1  // N` You can verify you get the same numerical result for any `c<0`, and see that must be since every term in the expression is of the form `c^(8-i)#1^i` or `c^8 (#1/c)^i`. I was not successful at finding an exact form simpler than the `RootExpression`.

Incidentally you might find this useful:

```
 Simplify[  root1 // ToRadicals ,  Assumptions -> {  c < 0 , a < root2  } ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Could you perhaps tell me what exact meaning of root2/c /. c -> -1  // N is? I guess it's the computation of the slope. However, I'm not familiar with this notation.

Comment: I was recently looking back at this post. It appears that Root2 = 11.1282c, however when I compute the second root of the 8th degree polynomial, I obtain 0.7c. It seems that Mathematica switch the orders?

Comment: the convention is to order the roots real first in increasing order. Remember c is negative so `11c < .7 c`

Comment: Of course! I was forgotten that c<0. Thanks again!